# Regex to match sentence ending punctuation without removing delimiter and join <p> tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all **sentence ending** punctuation in text file getting passed through to an html page by ajax in json format while keeping the delimiter and joining a `<p>` tag to each sentence.

Current code as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
  if(xhr.status === 200) {
    responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    var newContent = '';

    // text file html encasing
    newContent += '<p>' + responseObject.content + '</p>';

    // regex
    matchedPunctuation = newContent.match(/.*?[?!.]/g);

    // add element
    document.getElementById('myptag').innerHTML = matchedPunctuation.join('<p>');


  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/jsonstory', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

This fails me when I have a sentence as follows:

Short text file EXAMPLE .......  It is a nice day outsite. Dave said, "Yes it is."

The code above would add `<p>` tags to the first sentence correctly, which would be directly after the period but before the start of the next sentence.

The second sentence adds them between the period and quotation `.<p></p>` `"<p></p>`  which puts the quotation in a separate line from the sentence it should stay with on my html file. Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated!Thanks.

Comment: But i don't see anywhere in your code you're adding enclosing `</p>` how come it appear on output ? can you point out that part where you're adding `</p>` in case i missed it

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine, but when I open the output in the Chrome developer tools, it somehow adds them using the ```.join(<p>)``` I suppose I could enclose the response object with a closing tag, which is what I should do. Not to concerned with that though. Just the issue above. I will edit the question to match your suggestion

Comment: A quick check in console isn't seems to do what you said, i.e `['a','b'].join('<p>')` prints `a<p>b`

Comment: since your `?` is separator so it is desired to exclude the `"`, can you update rules under what circumstances your don't want you separator to be considered

Comment: I updated the question. All I am concerned with is sentence ending punctuation, not commas. Basically .!?  are the only three punctuation marks I need to be able to match. I am having trouble though because some of the sentences have quotes hanging at the end  of these punctuation marks. Therefore when i join the paragraph tag with the current expression above it joins it between the sentence ending punctuation and the quote. For these instances I want to join the paragraph tag after the quote but stil be able to join the paragraph tag after punctuation that does not have a quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex `.*?[?!.]"?` The `"?` makes it an optional requirement if the double quote is there or not. If it is, it uses it first for the match, if not, it just carries on.

Hopefully, this helps.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
  if(xhr.status === 200) {
    responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    var newContent = '';

    // text file html encasing
    newContent += '<p>' + responseObject.content + '</p>';

    // regex
    matchedPunctuation = newContent.match(/.*?[?!.]"?/g);

    // add element
    document.getElementById('myptag').innerHTML = matchedPunctuation.join('<p>');


  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/jsonstory', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. I would upvote your comment but new to the forum so I can't.

Comment: @NicholasRagan right below the comment upvote/downvote there should be a check mark. That is for the OP (you in this case) to select an answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Checked it. Thanks again.